# invalid composer file installing dependancy

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install a package found here :

https://cartalyst.com/manual/data-grid/3.0
my composer file is as follows :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
,  "barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator": "dev-master", "fzaninotto/faker": "1.2.*@dev", "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*", "cartalyst/data-grid": "3.0.*"  },

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
]



    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },


    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

unfortunately my json is invalid and I am having trouble fixing it I have followed the installation instructions as per the link at the start of the question thanks

Comment: You can easily check any syntax errors via http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comma between the `repositories` array and the `autoload` object.

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
...
```